# i'm creating a website that have multiple type of user and each user have a specific homepage, how can i define which page for the user using php?

Tags: php

i'm creating a website that have multiple type of user and each user have a specific homepage, how can i define which page for the user using php?
for example, there are students, superviser, admin
for each of them, there is specific homepage.

in my table, i create a row called role contain number that specify the type of the user 
i have wrote my code, but it does not move to the next page.

this is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect-db.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['pass']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $pwd = $_POST['pass'];   

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='$name' AND pass='$pwd'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $user=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$user[$row['id']] = array(
                    'ID' => $row['ID'],
                    'name'=>$row['name'],
                    'role'=>$row['role'],
                    'email'=>$row['e-mail'],
                    'pass' => $row['pass']
                    );

}

    if($result)
    {
        if((mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1))
        {

            header('Location: index.php?status=valid');
            if($user['role']===1){
            header('Location: Student_Home.php?status=valid');
            }
            if ($user['role']===3){
            header('Location: GPC.php?status=valid');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: index.php?status=invalid');
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Warning:** _Never store passwords in clear text!_ Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: `if mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1` then u are redirected to `index.php?status=valid`

Comment: Also, you're defining the user variable as `$user[$row['id']] = array(....)` (multidimensional array) but are trying to access the role using `$user['role']`. When defining the `$user`-data, define it with: `$user = array(...);` instead.

Comment: You are redirecting _any_ user to `index.php?status=valid`, as soon as the username-password checking query returns exactly one result. Only after that do you even start checking what $user['role'] contains. The whole code shows a lack of basic logical thinking. You check if you got a result from your database query at all only after you already tried to read data from it in the while loop, the while loop itself probably doesn’t know what it is doing there when the query should at most return one record to begin with, etc.

Comment: Since you're using three `===` when checking the role, you should do a `var_dump($user);` to see if `role` actually is an integer or if it's a string. MySQL often returns integers as strings (depending on the `mysqlnd` version on the server). You could just cast it as an integer though: `'role' => (int)$row['role']` to solve that issue.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you use a web application framework. It would solve some of the issues @MagnusEriksson highlighted above.